# Create Image in Java using 16 bit pixel data

Tags: java, image, grayscale

How can I create a grayscale image in Java using 16 bit pixel data stored in a short array?

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). There's a tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Hey may be this helpful to convert your short[] to BufferedImage..it is nicely worked for me try it out.
Here pix is my short array.